# Pandas How to Print a Certain Column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
     security_group    test     test_2   test_3
0          group a       1        Jon    blue
1          group b       2        bob    green
```

I want to print (not delete from the dataframe, just simply print. I don't want to actually modify the dataframe) 1 of the columns. For example:

```
      test_3
0       blue
1      green
```

I tried doing the following:

```
print(df([test_3]))
```

> This generates the following error message: NameError: name "test_3"
> is not defined

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

test_3 should be in quotes to denote that it is a string `"test_3"` otherwise python will think you're attempting to refer to a variable you named `test_3` and upon failure to find a variable named `test_3` you'll receive the error you're getting. Also your parentheses after `df` are incorrect. You only need square brackets:

```
print(df["test_3"])
```

Answer (score 4):

Use quotes around `column` name:

```
print(df['test_3'])
```

OR:

```
print(df.test_3)
```